# Make the output of a span the value of an input

Tags: javascript, php, html, jquery, css

Good day all, i am building a form that uses javascript to get a client's local time which is correctly displayed in span element. However i wish to make the output of the span element the value of an input field in order to pass same into mysql. I tried php like below, it rather displays the code.

```
$currenttradetime = "<span id='digital-clock'></span>";
$currenttt = $currenttradetime;
?>

<input type='hidden' name="time" value="<?php echo $currenttt; ?>"></span>'>
```

Then using html/php, it equally displays the span html codes rather than the time. How do i achieve this?

```js
function getDateTime() {
        var now     = new Date(); 
        var year    = now.getFullYear();
        var month   = now.getMonth()+1; 
        var day     = now.getDate();
        var hour    = now.getHours();
        var minute  = now.getMinutes();
        var second  = now.getSeconds(); 
        if(month.toString().length == 1) {
             month = '0'+month;
        }
        if(day.toString().length == 1) {
             day = '0'+day;
        }   
        if(hour.toString().length == 1) {
             hour = '0'+hour;
        }
        if(minute.toString().length == 1) {
             minute = '0'+minute;
        }
        if(second.toString().length == 1) {
             second = '0'+second;
        }   
        var dateTime = hour+':'+minute+':'+second;   
         return dateTime;
    }

    // example usage: realtime clock
    setInterval(function(){
        currentTime = getDateTime();
        document.getElementById("digital-clock").innerHTML = currentTime;
    }, 1000);
```

```html
The time is: <span id='digital-clock'></span>
    
    <input type='text' value='<span id="digital-clock"></span>'>
```

Comment: you cannot use HTML elements as the value of an input element like that unless you wish it to be treated as a string... just use Javascript instead to populate the input value directly

Comment: Do something like `document.getElementById('digital-clock').textContent = document.querySelector('input').value;`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Just use JavaScript to set the value of the input field like so:

```js
function getDateTime() {
        var now     = new Date(); 
        var year    = now.getFullYear();
        var month   = now.getMonth()+1; 
        var day     = now.getDate();
        var hour    = now.getHours();
        var minute  = now.getMinutes();
        var second  = now.getSeconds(); 
        if(month.toString().length == 1) {
             month = '0'+month;
        }
        if(day.toString().length == 1) {
             day = '0'+day;
        }   
        if(hour.toString().length == 1) {
             hour = '0'+hour;
        }
        if(minute.toString().length == 1) {
             minute = '0'+minute;
        }
        if(second.toString().length == 1) {
             second = '0'+second;
        }   
        var dateTime = hour+':'+minute+':'+second;   
         return dateTime;
    }

    // example usage: realtime clock
    setInterval(function(){
        currentTime = getDateTime();
        document.getElementById("digital-clock").innerHTML = currentTime;
        document.getElementById('time').value = currentTime;
    }, 1000);
```

```html
<span id="digital-clock"></span>
<input id="time" />
```

Answer (score 3):

Change

```
<input type='hidden' name="time" value="<?php echo $currenttt; ?>"></span>'>
```

to have an `id` too and do not set the html as value for the input field:

```
<input id='digital-clock-inputfield' type='hidden' name="time" value=""></span>'>
```

then change

```
document.getElementById("digital-clock").innerHTML = currentTime;
```

to set the value of the input field too:

```
document.getElementById("digital-clock").innerHTML = currentTime;
document.getElementById("digital-clock-inputfield").value = currentTime;
```